# How do you read input() as a string in python

Tags: string, python-3.x

I'm doing a practice problem where I need to read input from a string.

```
person_age = 6
person_name = ''
person_name = input()
print('In 5 years', person_name, 'will be', person_age + 5) #not editable
```

However, I get the error: `TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly`

I'm assuming it does this because person_name is read as an int even though a string is provided. How can I get this work? The catch is that I **cannot** edit the print line. I can only do this in 1 statement in place of `person_name = input()`. I googled it and saw to use raw_input instead but that function doesn't exist (Maybe I'm on python 3)

Comment: Could you please copy and paste the entire traceback and not just the `TypeError` line?

Comment: If you don't have `raw_input`, then you're on Python 3, and `input` always returns a string.  I just ran your code on both Python 2.7 & 3.5, and neither gave me an error.

Comment: Nothing interesting: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 7, in
    print('In 5 years', person_name, 'will be', person_age + 5)
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly`

Comment: Are you running the same code you show us? The error would happen if `person_age` was a string not an int. You could `print(repr(person_age))` to verify. BTW, put the traceback in question inside a code block for readability.

Comment: I ran your code and could not reproduce the problem.

Comment: Same here, runs fine

Comment: @tdelaney Here is a screenshot of the problem: https://i.snag.gy/0oS3xu.jpg

Comment: That's a different script than you posted. When you do `person_age = input()`, `person_age` is a string, not an integer. Its the character `"6"` (or whatever you typed in) not the number 6. You can do `person_age = int(input())` to get an int. But beware, other garbage entry such as `"hahaha"` raises a value error. I spent much more time on this than the time it would have taken you to enter the right script and run it. Checking your code is part of the engineering discipline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example I found:

1.`name = input("What's your name? ")`

2.`print("Nice to meet you " + name + "!")`

3.`age = input("Your age? ")`

4.`print("So, you are are already " + age + " years old, " + name + "!")`

The output will look like:

What's your name? "Frank"

Nice to meet you Frank!

Your age? 30

So, you are are already 30 years old, Frank!

Check the following website for more such examples:
http://www.python-course.eu/python3_input.php

Hope this helps!

Comment: OP is doing `person_age + 5` which he claims is giving the error - but its not, his code runs clean. In your case, `age` is a string and would raise OP's exception if you tried to add 5. He doesn't have a bug... but this answer does have the bug OP claims... but I don't think that makes it THE answer!